# PHP как указать путь к файлу который находится выше папки с сайтом?

Tags: php

Есть файл который хранится здесь:

> /home/n/myname/site/public_html/index.php

Необходимо из этого файла `index.php` указать путь к

> /home/n/myname/vendor/autoload.php

Comment: Ну вы можете сделать так `dirname(__DIR__);`. Можно ещё `__DIR__ . '/../'`

Comment: Я ничего не понял, dirname(__DIR__); возвращает такой путь - /home/n/myname/site (Мне нужен еще выше, на папке myname) Второй путь возвращает /home/j/jizziioc/nintendo/public_html/../ Что мне с ним делать? Можно более точный пример как мне подключить мой файл который хранится здесь?  /home/n/myname/vendor/autoload.php

Comment: Посмотрите сначала на мой комментарий, потом на свой, потом опять на мой. И так продолжайте до полного просветления

Comment: А объяснить можете? Какой смысл в dirname(__DIR__); если он возвращает папку с сайтом, а мне нужна папка на уровень выше

Comment: `dirname(__DIR__)` возвращает каталог родителя. Повторное использование `dirname` вернёт родителя родителя.

Comment: dirname(dirname(__DIR__)).'/vendor/autoload.php'; сделал так, если выводить через echo то путь правильный, но файл все равно не подключается, может нужно еще что-то указать?

Comment: указать имя файла недостаточно для его подключения. `require` и `include` - эти слова должны быть вам знакомы

Comment: все верно, я пишу require и путь к файлу

Comment: Warning: require(/home/j/jizziioc/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/j/jizziioc/nintendo/public_html/hook.php on line 7 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/j/jizziioc/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/j/jizziioc/nintendo/public_html/hook.php on line 7

Comment: дал права 777,  помогло